# Simple sql query, but stuck on it

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

[database mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QjzNm.png)

The only relevant table is 'employee' in the database model.

Asked: In which month are the most employee's birthdays?

By using

```
SELECT DATEPART(m, dateofbirth) AS month
FROM employee
```

I can actually see all the months for every employee and count it myself.

But how can I show the most common birthday month?

Thanks in advance!

[recent output (for comment below)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVQVt.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `GROUP BY`. This groups up the separate `month` values. Once you've done that, you can apply `COUNT`, and then order the values in descending order on that statistic. Then you need to wrap that logic in a Common Table Expression, so you can select just the months that have the maximum `COUNT`.

```
WITH ranking AS (
    SELECT 
    DATEPART(m, dateofbirth) AS month,
    COUNT(*) as ct
    FROM DM_MTA.dbo.employee
    GROUP BY DATEPART(m, dateofbirth) 
) 
select
month 
from
ranking
where ct = (select max(ct) from ranking)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but now the output has 2 columns.
It should only show 1 column with only the most frequent months.
I've added the output image (*) and marked the needed output in yellow.

Comment: How about accepting the answer and maybe even an upvote? :)

Answer (score 0):

This would give you exact month you're looking for:

```
SELECT TOP 1 DATEPART(m, dateofbirth) AS month
FROM employee
GROUP BY DATEPART(m, dateofbirth)
ORDER BY count(DATEPART(m, dateofbirth)) DESC
```